# Setting up WiFi on ArchLinux

Tags: networking, archlinux

**Question**

I have a USB wifi dongle. I am running Arch Linux on my Pi. How would I connect to my network, despite the fact that my wi-fi has a password?

**Thoughts**

I am trying to find out where and how I can set up my wifi USB adapter in Arch. I assume it would either be in dev or the adapter. The config file for the wifi would most likely be in etc. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of `lsusb` and make sure that the device is being detected. Then, check `ip a` and see if it shows the device in the list. If not then you'll have to use the information given about the device from `lsusb` or if you already know the device's make and model then you can just use that. Then do some research to find out what modules the device requires. Next, check `pacman` and the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org) for the modules that your wireless interface requires.

Once installed, you can use `modprobe` to load the module and then recheck `ip a` to confirm that the device is now being recognized by the system. Then you can use either [netcfg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netcfg) or [netctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl) to setup your network network configuration accordingly. Both network managers have great examples and documentation that will help you along the way.

**NOTE** - `netctl` is in the [testing] repository at the moment. You will need to make sure that this is uncommented in `/etc/pacman.conf` in order to activate the repository. In the future `netctl` will be replacing `netcfg`. Best of luck.