# Set up Edimax EW-7811UN WiFi dongle?

Tags: wifi, archlinux, driver

I have an [Edimax EW-7811UN WiFi dongle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CLMJLU) and I want to use it to connect to my WiFi on Arch Linux 3.10.18-1-ARCH+ (taken from the login prompt, not sure if that's correct. I'm new to Arch). I went with Arch because it is supposed to be lighter. If Raspbian would be a better choice for running a *very* small Bukkit server, please let me know, as that's my current project that I'm doing for the kicks.

I would like to do most of my work on the Pi over SSH , as the screen I have *really* sucks and everything is really tiny and I have to sit way hunched over to use the Pi.

However, I can't download updates or the stuff needed to run the server. I have been googling around and everything I see says I have to use `pacman`, but that is out of the question, as I have *no* access short of the WiFi adapter (I can't get the Pi close enough for ethernet to the router.)

I have looked at [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5580/setting-up-wifi-on-archlinux%20and%20I%20have%20been%20researching) and [this thread](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=6100), which tells me to run `dmesg -v | grep usbcore` which returns a bunch of stuff, and the response closest to the one the thread says to look for, is `rt18192cm`. However, searching that in Arch AUR doesn't return anything.

[This thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=7471) looked like it would work, but the top link is dead!

What should I be looking for? I am comfortable with compiling software, if need be, and I have a USB hub, so I can transfer files to the Pi that way. Where can I find the driver necessary to run this dongle and how should I install it?

Comment: You have an up-to-date version of Arch Linux, right?

Comment: @syb0rg I believe so. Downloaded it from the RPi site less than 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Can you get access to internet temporarily?  Even if you have to run commands blindly?  It would make all of this a lot easier.

Comment: I could try... what commands?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The driver you need is in the repositories.

```
pacman -Sy dkms-8192cu
```

If you could get internet access temporarily, you could simply download and install it.

Comment: What keypresses will I have to do after running this command? Eg. `y` or `enter`

Comment: You might have to confirm the download if the files are large enough.  Press enter a few times after you enter the command, with some delay in between each key press.

Comment: Ok! Will go and try this!

Comment: Any easy way to do this offline? In Debian I could probably download a .deb file to USB and install it with dpkg. Is it that easy in Arch?

Comment: `error: target not found: dkms-8192cu`. The package you want is called `8192cu-dkms` and is in the AUR (i.e., it must be install using an AUR helper, such as `packer`).

Answer (score 1):

As the commented on @syB0rg's answer by [Sean the Bean](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/35790/sean-the-bean), you need `packer` to install the `8192cu-dkms` package. To do so:

First install `packer`

```
pacman -Sy packer
```

Than install `8192cu-dkms`

```
packer 8192cu-dkms
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get this wifi dongle working with the `dkms-8192cu` package, as suggested in other answers.  It simply wouldn't recognize the device.  Note that `dkms-8192cu` is currently in the `alarm` repository, so it can be installed directly with `pacman`, not from AUR.  But since it doesn't work any more, that's not very helpful.

What *did* work for me was the following:

1. Installing the `rtl8812au-rpi-dkms-git` package from AUR using the following commands:

   ```
   wget https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/rtl8812au-rpi-dkms-git.tar.gz
   bsdtar xzf rtl8812au-rpi-dkms-git.tar.gz
   cd rtl8812au-rpi-dkms-git
   makepkg -si
   ```
2. Enabling the use of the `wext` driver instead of `nl80211`, which basically means you need to run `wpa_supplicant` with the argument `-Dwext` or `-Dnl80211,wext`.  To do that, I followed the suggestion in [the arch WPA supplicant page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#nl80211_driver_not_supported_on_some_hardware) (as root):

   ```
   wpa_supplicant my_ssid my_passphrase > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
   mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service.d
   cat >/etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service.d/wext.conf <<EOF
   [Service]
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%I.conf -i%I -Dnl80211,wext
   EOF
   systemctl daemon-reload
   systemctl enable --now wpa_supplicant@wlan0
   ```